If the open cover U of the topological space has a partition of unity then U has a locally finite refinement.
In the of Engelking Book "General Topology in the chapter of paracompactness there is a lemma related to partition of unity and locally finite refinement. In the lemma it is given that $$f_{s}(x)<g(x), x\in U_{0},s\in S\setminus S_{0}     \hspace{40 pt}(1)$$ where $U_{0}=\lbrace x\in X:1-\sum_{i=1}^{k}f_{s}(x)<g(x)\rbrace$ satisfy (1).
Also, it is said that for every $x\in X$ the exists an $s(x)\in S$ such that $f_{s(x)}(x)>0$. Letting $g(x)=f_{s}(x)$ in (1) we infer that the formula
$f(x)=\underset{s\in S}{\sup}f_{s}(x)$ defines a continuous function $f:X\to(0,1]$. I am blocked to prove that in this case.
How can I prove it?

Which part is unclear for you, exactly? Is it the continuity of $f$?

Yes the continuity, because the function is well defined due to the definition.

To begin we need that $f=\sup_{s\in S}\{f_s\}$ is continuous if and only if it is continuous locally (this is Engelking's Corollary 2.1.12). We will demonstrate that $f$ is locally continuous.
Since $\{f_s\}_{s\in S}$ is a partition of unity, the equation $\sum_{s\in S}f_s(x)=1$ holds throughout $X$. What this is supposed to mean is that for any given $x\in X$, there are only countably many $s\in S$ satisfying $f_s(x)\neq 0$, that for any finite subset $S_0\subseteq S$ it holds that $\sum_{s\in S_0}f_s(x)\leq 1$, and that for any $\epsilon>0$ there is a finite subset $S_0\subseteq S$ for which $\sum_{s\in S_0}f_s(x)>1-\epsilon$.

Lemma For any $\epsilon>0$, each $x_0\in X$ has a neighbourhood $U_0$ on which $f_s<\epsilon$ throughout $U_0$ for all but finitely many $s\in S$.

Proof Fix $x_0\in X$ and choose a finite $S_0\subset S$ for which $\sum_{s\in S_0}f_s(x_0)>1-\epsilon$. Then
$$U_0=\{x\in X\mid \sum_{s\in S_0}f_s(x)>1-\epsilon\}$$
is an open set containing $x_0$. If $x\in U_0$ and $f_t(x)\geq \epsilon$, then $t$ must belong to $S_0$. For otherwise
$$f_t(x)+\sum_{s\in S_0}f_s(x)>1,$$
which contradicts the fact that $\{f_s\}_{s\in S}$ is a partition of unity. $\qquad\blacksquare$
Now, $\{f_s\}_{s\in S}$ is a partition of unity, so given $x_0\in X$ there is $t\in S$ such that $0<f_t(x_0)\leq 1$. Put $\epsilon=f_t(x_0)$ and let $U_0$ be as in the lemma. Then the lemma states that the set
$$T=\{s\in S\mid f_s(x)\geq\epsilon\;\text{some}\;x\in U_0\}$$
is finite. Consequently
$$f|_{U_0}=\max\{f_s|_{U_0}\mid s\in T\}.$$
The right-hand side is continuous on $U_0$, since a maximum of finitely many continuous functions is continuous. The equation says that throughout the open set $U_0$, the supremum $f=\sup\{f_s\}$ evaluates as the maximum of some finite set.
